# Grails: Same URL Mapping to different actions per different HTTP methods

Tags: grails, url-mapping, http-method, controller-action

I'm using Grails v3.2.9

In official documentation I found the following for [mapping to http methods](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.9/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingHTTP):

```
static mappings = {
   "/product/$id"(controller:"product", action: "update", method: "PUT")
}
```

But this is not enough. What I need is to have one mapping which maps to different actions(in the same controller) based on HTTP method.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add URLMappings like --

```
"/product/api/v2/book" (controller: 'book') {
    action = [GET: 'show', POST: 'update']
}
```

Also, it is good to add method constraint in controller --

```
  static allowedMethods = [show: 'GET', update: 'POST']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you follow the method naming convention for REST controllers... you could get away with:

```
"/product/$id" (resources:'product')
```

Here's some good info:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-customize-resource.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my case is calling exactly same URL mapped to different actions for GET and POST .

Comment: That's fine, and the other answer should work well for that case.  I didn't read that the same URL was required in your question.